# Eclipse package error，but all his childPackage has no error

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I check out my code from svn, but one package has errors ,but  all his sub-packages have no red-error icon.

[error img http://postimg.org/image/o2veg9811/](http://postimg.org/image/o2veg9811/)

All my project is based on 'aiis-framework' project ,So I want to make the aiis-framework project correct first.

Before I ask this question, I do 'Project->Clean' in eclipse ,and 'mvn clean  compile -Dmaven.test.skip' in maven again and again ,but nothing changed.

If someone give me some advice ,it will do me a big favor.

Additional:I see the problems, it says my pom-file is not up-to-date。
But I runs these in my cmd.exe

> mvn clean  compile -Dmaven.test.skip 
>   mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -Dmaven.test.skip
>   mvn resources:resources

Then refresh in the eclipse.
what it happens 'pom is not up-to-date'

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: So your problem is that you want to know, what actually Eclipse is complaining about? As a first step, try the problems view (Window > Show View > Problems)

Comment: @LostAvatar GoodIdea,I find eclipse is complaining 'pom.xml is not up-to-date'. I run the maven command befor, why it happened ?

Comment: @user1423581 I found it is pom.xml is not up-to-date.How to fix it?

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418630/eclipse-blue-maven-project-configuration-is-not-up-to-date-with-pom-xml for me. One answer there proposes Maven Update Project