# Execution default of goal com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8:process failed

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data, spring-boot, m2e

Once I added the  com.mysema.querydsl into the pom.xml. I got the following error
Please advise.

Execution default of goal com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8:process failed: Plugin com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.8 () (com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8:process:default:generate-sources)

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>spring-boot-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-mvc-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.8</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>   
</project>
```

Comment: The log will normally tell you which dependencies could not be found. Did you miss that out of your copy-paste? Maybe there is a mouldy download sitting in your local cache (try blowing away the ones that are problematic from `~/.m2/repository`)?

Comment: Cleaning ~/.m2/repository did not help. There is no message in Error Log. Only one message in Problems tab which is Execution default of goal com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8:process failed: Plugin com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.8 () (com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8:process:default:generate-sources). I am using STS.

Comment: This worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418630/eclipse-blue-maven-project-configuration-is-not-up-to-date-with-pom-xml

Comment: Solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418630/eclipse-blue-maven-project-configuration-is-not-up-to-date-with-pom-xml isn't stable. The error came back.

Comment: Maybe try not running Maven from Eclipse. Use the command line and mark that plugin as ignored in the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: In My case commenting execution tag and then uncomment solve identical problem. Still only eclipse issue.