# mvn Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

When I run mvn clean deploy on my project I get an error

Also my project in eclipse displays the following errors which I don't know if they are related to my current problem.

Project configuration not up-to-date with pom.xml
plugin configuration not covered by lifecycle configuration

In addition my eclipse doesn't seems to compile the files correctly. My SpringBoot java files aren't being compiled as java files. I can tell because if I deliberately induce syntax errors, there isn't a compilation error. This is all run on eclipse EE and is part of a maven project so I don't even know if a source folder is needed.

Also I'm displaying my main pom.xml file below and it has compilation errors on  "pom" and both "&ndash"

I've tried the following solutions

[Eclipse Blue, Maven: Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418630/eclipse-blue-maven-project-configuration-is-not-up-to-date-with-pom-xml)

[Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742467/failed-to-resolve-version-for-org-apache-maven-archetypes)

[repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDep loymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153024/repository-element-was-not-specified-in-the-pom-inside-distributionmanagement-el)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.fanniemae.dfc</groupId>
<artifactId>dfc_app</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>dfc_angular</module>
    <module>dfc_springBoot</module>
</modules>

<!--<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> &lt;!&ndash; lookup parent from repository 
&ndash;&gt;
</parent>-->

</project>
```

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project dfc_app: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter

Answer (score 4):

`mvn deploy` will deploy the produced artifact to a Maven Repository.

To do so it needs the configuration to which repository it must be deployed and this is missing.

But I assume that you don't want to deploy it to a repository but just build it.

That's `mvn install` This will install it in your local repository.

Maybe you should start with reading the docs: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: it said build successful when I ran mvn install

Comment: I'm still not able to deploy it

Comment: Where do you want to deploy it?

Comment: TBH I don't know but preferably the default location

Comment: Again my question. Do you mean by deploy to install your software to run it? And what do you mean by default location?